# calling a method from within a for statement in java

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, methods

I'm still a pretty novice programmer so please excuse my messing code. When I try to compile the following code I get the error:

```
The method Customer(java.lang.String, java.lang.Double) is undefined for the type Customer
```

I have previously attempted to declare the object "s" within the for statement, it then creates a new error at the end of the program where I reference the object "s" again. I was wondering how I could get around this problem? Below I have included my current program, along with the desired output and `Customer.class API`.

[API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JakaJ.png)

[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giduO.png)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A4
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        //delcaring variables
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        String[] name = new String[5];
        Double[] amount = new Double[5];
        Customer s = new Customer( "", 0 );
        //begining of program
        for ( int i = 0; i <= 5; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println( "please enter the name of the customer" );
            name[i] = input.next();
            System.out.println( "please enter the amount in that account" );
            amount[i] = input.nextDouble();

            s.Customer( name[i], amount[i] );
            //Customer s = new Customer(name [i],amount[i]);
        }
        System.out.println( "Search for all customers who have more than $100" );
        for ( int t = 0; t <= 5; t++ )
        {
            if ( amount[t] >= 100 )
            {
                System.out.println( name[t] );
            }
        }

        Double avgBalance = 0.0;
        for ( int r = 1; r <= 5; r++ )
        {
            avgBalance += r;
        }
        avgBalance = avgBalance / 5;

        System.out.println( "The average balance is: " + avgBalance );

        Double max = amount[1];
        for ( int j = 0; j <= 5; j++ )
        {
            if ( amount[j] > max )
            {
                max = amount[j];
            }
        }
        System.out.println( "The customer with the highest balance is: " + max );

        System.out.println( "Show all accounts after a 5% balance increase" );

        //Customer c = new Customer(name [i],amount[i]);
        for ( int e = 0; e <= 5; e++ )
        {
            //Customer c = new Customer amount[e].applyPercentageIncrease(5);
            //amount [e]=
            //applyPercentageIncrease q = new 
            s.applyPercentageIncrease( 5 );
            System.out.println( s.getName() + " has " + s.getBalance() );
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: i have implemented what Gtomika suggested and the program now runs, however in the first for statement, the program asks the user for 6 names then sets an out of bounds error, i understand the out of bounds error, however the for statement conditions state that it should only ask for 5 names and 5 balances right? am i missing something here?

UPDATE2: I have fixed the above problem and have improved my program, now i need some help in using the method `applyPercentageIncrease` from the `Customer.class` API. I am aware the code i wrote below is not functional, but i would appreciate some help with applying a 5% increase to all account balances using the method stated above. thanks

```
    for (int e=0;e<5;e++)
{
  //Customer c = new Customer amount[e].applyPercentageIncrease(5);
  //amount [e]=
  //applyPercentageIncrease q = new 
  customers[o]=e.applyPercentageIncrease(5);
  System.out.println (o.getName()+" has "+o.getBalance());

}
```

Comment: You're trying to call a constructor as if it was a method. Take a step back, and read your text book again to learn what a method is, and what a constructor is. And find the keyboard shortcut of your IDE that allows formatting your code, because it's unreadable as it is now.

Comment: unfortunately no, as i received the customer.class file itself, im not sure how to open it though lol

Comment: don't what you're doing, but in the first for loop you'll clearly overwrite name and amount because you're not creating a new customer in each iteration. And there is no `Customer` method, you have to call the constructor with `new Customer(...)`. Please start again with a Java tutorial

Comment: @JBNizet thank you for your response, the code in my IDE is properly formatted, however when transferring it here the formatting gets a little messed up, i can include a screenshot of my code in my IDE if you would like

Comment: @AKSW thanks for the reply, like i stated im pretty new to programming in general, could you give me an idea of how to create a seperate customer each time please?

Comment: I can't see how that would be possible. Stackoverflow doesn't randomly add or remove spaces from what you post. Format your code, then edit your question, remove the code, then paste the code from your IDE, select it all, and press Ctrl-K

Comment: @TheUltimateAssasin11 you got the answer already below

Comment: yes, i saw it, thank you. i will reformat it, and edit the post. sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

You should also declare and array (or perhaps an ArrayList or LinkedList) of Customer objects:

```
Customer[] customers = new Customer[5];
```

This way in the for loop you can say:

```
for (int i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
  System.out.println("please enter the name of the customer");
  name[i] = input.next();
  System.out.println("please enter the amount in that account");
  amount[i] = input.nextDouble();

  customers[i] = new Customer(name[i],amount[i]); //set the i. element of the Customer array
}
```

Now you can reference the created Customer objects after this loop!